# Apply different array to each column and print results from each array programmatically?

Tags: r, arrays, awk

I have a table with many columns (fields). In the first field, I need to retain only unique values. In the subsequent columns, I need to count the original number of values present in the first column, but only if the value in a given column is > 0.

I've managed to partially accomplish this with `awk`, but my current attempt would require me to manually create an array for every column in the table *and* manually type each array for the print command. This isn't really feasible.

Any help/suggestions (and explanation of how a potential solution works) would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a subset of the INPUT TABLE (it has already been sorted on column 1):

```
ATP6          93.883156   55.84006
COX1          230.708456  63.109
COX2          179.993226  74.224269
COX3          169.945901  72.036519
CYTB          228.799722  87.575892
LOC111099029  0.926958    6.124982
LOC111099030  10.124096   5.024844
LOC111099031  0           0
LOC111099031  0           0
LOC111099031  2.279801    2.289838
LOC111099032  17.674714   12.796428
LOC111099033  5.259716    7.326938
LOC111099034  3.514635    2.858349
LOC111099035  0           0
LOC111099035  1.929607    4.409107
LOC111099036  0           0
LOC111099036  1.45196     7.58513
LOC111099037  21.520663   26.353308
LOC111099038  6.019084    5.311657
LOC111099039  12.858404   13.689644
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0           0
LOC111099040  0.354202    0.265986
LOC111099040  0.587969    0
LOC111099040  2.620288    1.077892
LOC111099040  4.290659    3.487692
LOC111099040  6.42671     6.906503
LOC111099041  0           0
LOC111099041  3.892818    4.934959
LOC111099042  0           0
LOC111099042  13.86859    14.319505
LOC111099043  0           0
```

Here's an example of the DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
LOC111099030  1  1
CYTB          1  1
LOC111099042  1  1
LOC111099037  1  1
LOC111099033  1  1
COX3          1  1
ATP6          1  1
LOC111099039  1  1
LOC111099036  1  1
LOC111099040  5  4
LOC111099035  1  1
LOC111099032  1  1
COX2          1  1
LOC111099038  1  1
LOC111099031  1  1
COX1          1  1
LOC111099029  1  1
LOC111099041  1  1
LOC111099034  1  1
```

Here's the code I've run to obtain the output above:

```
awk '{if ($2 > 0) gene_name[$1]++}; {if ($3 > 0) col3_arr[$1]++}; END{ for (var in gene_name) print var, "\t", gene_name[var], col3_arr[var]}' input_file.txt
```

P.S. I'm also open to a solution in `R`, as this manipulation is part of a larger R Markdown notebook. I went the `awk` route because I'm not particularly well-versed with `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
desired_result = your_data %>%
  group_by(name_of_first_column) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(. > 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, we may use `rowsum`

```
rowsum(+(df1[-1] > 0), df1[[1]])
```